# Make whole parent div a clickable zone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

This question has probably been answered many times, but I need help because I cannot achieve what I intend to do.

I have this view:

```
<div class="bookView">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="bookUnit" onclick="$@Url.Action("SeeBook", new { bookID = Model[i].BookID})">
            <span class="linkSpan"></span>
            <div class="bookTitle" data-id="@Model[i].BookID">
                @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].BookName) 
            </div>    
            <div class="bookDetail">
                <div class="bookCategory">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item =>_item[i].Category.CategoryName)
                </div>
                <div class="bookEditor">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].Editor.EditorName)
                </div>
                <div class="bookDate">
                    @Model[i].DateAdded.ToShortDateString()
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bookScore">
                Score: @Html.DisplayFor(_item => _item[i].Score)
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And here's the related CSS:

```
.linkSpan {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*top:0;*/
    /*left: 0;*/
    display: block;
    /* edit: added z-index */
    z-index: 1;
    /* edit: fixes overlap error in IE7/8, 
        make sure you have an empty gif */
    /*background-image: url('empty.gif');*/
}

.bookView {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.bookView div {
    padding: 5px;
}

.bookUnit {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    z-index: 0;
}

.bookUnit:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.bookTitle {
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.bookDetail {
    float: left;
}

.bookScore {
    float: left;
}
```

So the goal is that the whole `bookUnit` div with all its content would become a clickable zone which would carry the ID to my controller method. There's abount 20 `books` per loops, but each div would carry its own ID.

I've tried the `anchor` method as you can see, but it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to include the JavaScript code at the moment,
check [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/) to do so.

but there is a tricky way to achieve this using a CSS code
you must nest an anchor tag inside your div tag and you must apply this property to it,

```
display:block;
```

when you've done that,it will make the whole width area clickable (but within the height of the anchor tag),if you want to cover the whole div area you must set the height of the anchor tag exactly to the height of the div tag,for example:

```
height:60px;
```

this is gonna make the whole area clickable,then you can apply `text-indent:-9999px` to anchor tag to achieve the goal.

this is really tricky and simple and it's just created using CSS code.

here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/): http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/RG8wW/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the whole thing clickable, bind the `click` event to it. You can access its ID with `attr()`:

```
$(".bookUnit").click(function(){
    var bookId = $(this).attr("id");
    //Do stuff
});
```